# Docker for Windows can't hit RabbitMQ ip unless port is bound to localhost

Tags: docker, rabbitmq

Trying to build a dev environment for rabbitmq and some other services. Reading docker hub I should be able to access RabbitMQ management after getting the image found here (https://hub.docker.com/_/rabbitmq/) up by going to http://container-ip:15672 . That doesn't work for me. If I expose port 15672 so localhost:15672 maps to the containers 15672 I can access expected output via http://localhost:15672. Still pretty new to docker so think there is something basic about the networking I'm missing here. I'd prefer to not bind ports on the localhost like that if possible.

Dockerfile

```
FROM rabbitmq:3-management

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends vsftpd \
    && apt-get clean \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN mkdir -p /var/run/vsftpd/empty \
 && mkdir -p /etc/vsftpd \
 && mkdir -p /var/ftp \
 && mv /etc/vsftpd.conf /etc/vsftpd.orig \
 && mkdir -p /etc/service/vsftpd

ADD vsftpd.sh /etc/service/vsftpd/run
VOLUME ["/var/ftp"]

EXPOSE 20-21
EXPOSE 65500-65515
```

DockerRun.bat

```
docker build -t dev-environment .
docker run -d --hostname my-rabbit --name some-rabbit -it dev-environment 
docker inspect --format "RabbitMQ management @ http://{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}:15672" some-rabbit
```

Output from docker inspect

```
docker inspect --format "RabbitMQ management @ http://172.17.0.2:15672" some-rabbit
```

Comment: Why are you installing an FTP daemon?  Why are you looking up the container-private IP address?  How are you launching the container (what `docker run -p` options do you have)?  When you do try to invoke http://localhost:15672 what error do you get?

Comment: Hey @DavidMaze I'm installing an FTP daemon because the dev project i'm working on is setting up a modern event system that will will respond when a legacy system does FTP uploads to a location. I have proven the system out with live machines, but my company wants me to containerize the system for testing and development. 

The run command is in the .bat file above. I was hoping I didn't have to use -p and bind a local port.  I have been able to get it to work by doing that and getting it to work over localhost. I was hoping to get it to work without that like the hub page I linked says.

Comment: You need two separate containers, and you pretty much always need a `-p` option to make ports accessible from outside the container.  The `docker inspect` IP address is an implementation detail that doesn't work in many common contexts (including it doesn't work at all on Windows hosts).

Comment: Ah so Docker for Windows that functionality just doesn't work? Ok, that may be the thing. The documentation specifically says you don't have to use -p and can connect via the internal ip . That would be a preferred methodology for a local test environment so it doesn't interfere with other things. I can do a docker compose file and use 2 different containers. I'm pretty new to docker and this is my first time using it. So any insight is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Simply need to bind ports when running the container, so

```
docker run -d --hostname my-rabbit --name some-rabbit -p15672:15672 -p5672:5672 -it dev-environment
```

potentially you can use -P to publish all exposed ports. See [docker run reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/)

EDIT:

if you don't want to bind ports to localhost (TBH I see no reason why not to :) ) but sill want to open the management UI from the browser on your host, you cold run the container in the host network by passing `--network=host` and then figure out the IP address given to that container using docker inspect...

Comment: Hey @cantSleepNow I was trying to avoid that and run it from the internal ip address like the rabbitmq hub mentioned was possible. It was mentioned that functionality doesn't work on windows so looks like i'll have to do the above. I had gotten it to work like that before.

Comment: ah sorry and thanks for clearing it up, I'll edit  my answer